# Symfony Form Querybuilder with parameters

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine

I have the need to create a dropdown field with grouped data:

My form:

```
class RetailerDetailFilterType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getActiveRetailerMetrics(): array
    {
        return range(25,36);
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('month', EntityType::class,
            [
                'class' => 'AppBundle:ConsolidatedOperatorCategoryLowData',
                'query_builder' => function(ConsolidatedOperatorCategoryLowDataRepository $er){
                    return $er->getMinMaxByMetricQueryBuilder($this->getActiveRetailerMetrics());
                }
            ]);

    }


    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'key_metric';
    }
}
```

My Repository:

```
    class ConsolidatedOperatorCategoryLowDataRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getMinMaxByMetricQueryBuilder($metricRange)
    {
        $qb = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder('d');
        $qb
            ->select('d.id, YEAR(d.date) as dyear, MONTH(d.date) as dmonth')
            ->from('AppBundle:ConsolidatedOperatorCategoryLowData','d')
            ->where($qb->expr()->in('d.metric_id', $metricRange))
            ->groupBy('dyear')
            ->addGroupBy('dmonth')
            ->setMaxResults(10)
            ;
        return $qb;

    }
```

I'm getting

```
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, integer given


at UnitOfWork ->isScheduledForInsert (3182005) 
in vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php at line 710       + 
at EntityManager ->contains (3182005) 
in     vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/ChoiceList/IdReader.php at line 116   + 
at IdReader ->getIdValue (3182005) 
at call_user_func (array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), 3182005) 
in     vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php at line 205   + 
at ArrayChoiceList ->flatten (array('id' => 3182005, 'dyear' => '2016', 'dmonth' => '12'), array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), array(), array(), null) 
in     vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php at line 200   + 
at ArrayChoiceList ->flatten (array(array('id' => 3182005, 'dyear' => '2016', 'dmonth' => '12'), array('id' => 3186685, 'dyear' => '2017', 'dmonth' => '1'), array('id' => 3191365, 'dyear' => '2017', 'dmonth' => '2'), array('id' => 3195595, 'dyear' => '2017', 'dmonth' => '3'), array('id' => 3200275, 'dyear' => '2017', 'dmonth' => '4')), array(object(IdReader), 'getIdValue'), array(), array(), array(null)) 
in    vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/ChoiceList/ArrayChoiceList.php at line 91
```

Comment: Your querybuilder returns more than an entity (dyear, dmonth), I don't think the FormType can handle that. Try replacing your select-call with this one: `select('d, YEAR(d.date) AS HIDDEN dyear, MONTH(d.date) AS HIDDEN dmonth')`. This ofcourse assumes that you don't actually need the values for dmonth and dyear anywhere else apart from the groupBy.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with how Doctrine ORM deals with relationships. When you want to retrieve an entity by a referenced object's id, say find all posts by a user id, then you still have to pass the User-object to the QueryBuilder, not just the id. This is because Doctrine will resolve how those entities are connected itself.

It seems that `metric_id` actually is a reference to some kind of Metric-entity and just passing an array of int instead of the actual objects seems to trip up Doctrine's QueryBuilder.

You could try mapping the id's to a new instance of Metric and then pass that array instead.

Another solution - the one I would prefer - is to use [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) for this.